# extracting a string up to a string within a long string in php

Tags: php, string

i have searched through the Internet and found a solution to this but it do it in a reverse order.

**original string**

```
S0597 KIPATIMU SECONDARY DIV-I = 0  DIV-II = 3
```

**string to be extracted**

```
S0597 KIPATIMU SECONDARY

extraction should stop when "DIV-" is reached.
```

**my code output**

```
DIV-I = 0  DIV-II = 3
```

**here is my code.**

```
if(($pos = strpos($string, 'DIV-')) !== false)
{
  $school_name = substr($string, $pos);
}
else
{
   $school_name = get_last_word($string);
}
echo $school_name;
```

how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$str_value='S0597 KIPATIMU SECONDARY DIV-I = 0  DIV-II = 3' //store your string value

In PHP there is many function availble for these you have used the more than one function to achive these.

stristr($str_value,"DIV-",true); //these function return the o/p : **S0597 KIPATIMU SECONDARY**

If you change the last argument from *'true'* to *'false'* it will return the **DIV-I = 0  DIV-II = 3**

Answer (score 1):

```
$school_name = substr($string, $pos);
```

It means you are assigning `$school_name` with substring of `$string`, start from where the `DIV-` reached to the end of `$string`.

You need to start it from `0` until the position where `DIV-` is reached.

```
$school_name = substr($string, 0, $pos);
```

Answer (score 1):

you get extraction string in $school_name then replace this with blank from full string and you will get output try

```
if(($pos = strpos($string, 'DIV-')) !== false)
{
  $school_name = substr($string, $pos);
  $school_name = str_replace($school_name, '', $string);
}
// output - S0597 KIPATIMU SECONDARY
```